# Can't read resources files from apk

Tags: android, file-io, resources, inputstream

My application includes some .txt files that it needs to read.

I used to read them using the Inputstream:

```
Class c = this.getClass();
   InputStream is = c.getResourceAsStream("/fileName.txt");
```

for efficiency reasons I needed to read them using the RandomAccessFile.

Because I can't use the c.getResourceAsStream() I need to find another way to get the files.

I tried the following code:

```
Class c = this.getClass();
URL fileURL = c.getResource("/fileName.txt");
File file =new File(fileURL.getPath());
```

or

```
File file =new File(fileURL.toURI());
```

but wasn't able to locate the file.

I think I'm missing something fundamental, can someone please help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where do you have your file initially? Is it in raw folder, assets folder...?

Comment: Move it inside the `assets` folder and open it like `InputStream is = this.getAssets().open("fileName.txt");`

Answer (score 2):

Just wanting to add a little more detail here to explain why `File file =new File(fileURL.getPath());` wont work. Everything in your application is contained in your .akp file which is just a renamed .zip file. This means when your application is requesting a file  from the assets directory no file actually exists at that path. using `InputStream is = this.getAssets().open("fileName.txt");` will open the apk and look there instead.